# SoapUI Open source : How to get test case status [ FINISHED / FAILED ] which is in another project

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am facing issue with Ant build file when i run Project1 with Project2 [controller]

Here my project structure is like below

> Controller.xml [Project2] which loads the test data dynamically  in Project1.xml and executes the test cases in project1 .
>   I made an ant build file to integrate with Jenkins .
>   Now when i run this Controller.xml , then Ant would run Controller.xml and it executes the Project1.xml test cases with valid and invalid

Here my issue with Ant build status :
1. I am getting BUILD SUCCESS message even few of test cases got failed in Project1.xml while executing from ANT build , why  because Controller.xml will reuturn always FINSIHED status

Here my thought is that , 
Is there any way to get status of test cases which are in project1 to write assert script in project2

Can anyone please help

Comment: I believe ant's job is to execute the target and that is successfully completed, so is BUILD SUCCESS. What you would be needed to do, IMO,  is to pass the arguments to testrunner so that it will generate the junit test reports while executing the tests and create html reports where you can the individual test reports. May http://softwaretestersforum.blogspot.in/2013/03/generate-junit-style-html-reports-in.html will help you understand better.

Comment: @Rao : Thanks for the reply , i am already writing up the results in excel sheets .